# Determine friends / friend requested / not friends using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table:

[image]

Let's imagine I am logged in as user 1 and I'm browsing the profile of user 2. As we are mutual friends (1 is friend with 2 and 2 is friend with 1), I need to echo "friends."

When I browse the profile of user 4, whose friendship I have requested, but they haven't accepted yet, I need to echo "friend requested."

When browsing any other user, I need to echo "add friend."

I can do the PHP part, I just don't know how to do the MySQL query.

Comment: Perhaps start by showing us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and why it isn't working for you?

Comment: @eggyal I could go and list all 30 queries I tried, however I'm not sure that would be of any help, as none of them had worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, `user` 
FROM `friends`
WHERE 
    (`user` = 1 AND `friend` = 16) OR 
    (`user` = 16 AND `friend` = 1)
```

When `count` is

- 2 = mutual (you are friend with that person)
- 1 and `user` is you - you requested that person friendship
- 1 and `user` is that person - you are being requested for friendship by that person
- 0 = no connection between you and that person

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case 
    when subquery.a > 0 and subquery.b > 0 then 'friends'
    when subquery.a > 0 then 'friend requested'
    else 'add friend' end) as "friend_string"
from (
    select
        (select count(*) from relationships where user = '$my_user_id' and friend = '$opponent_user_id') as a,
        (select count(*) from relationships where user = '$opponent_user_id' and friend = '$my_user_id') as b
) subquery
```

Please replace `relationships` with your table name, and $ variables with yours.

Comment: Zero rows, really? How did you execute the query, in your PHP program, or phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this? (just for the sql part, not the PHP :) )

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ccd/8)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a. user, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN a.user = b.friend 
                       AND a.friend = b.user THEN b.friend 
                  ELSE '' 
                end friends, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN a.user = b.friend 
                       AND a.friend <> b.user THEN a.friend 
                  ELSE '' 
                end friendreq, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN a.user <> b.friend 
                       AND a.friend <> b.user THEN a.friend 
                  ELSE '' 
                end addfriend 
FROM   demo a 
       LEFT JOIN demo b 
              ON a.id > b.id;
```

```
| USER | FRIENDS | FRIENDREQ | ADDFRIEND |
------------------------------------------
|    1 |         |           |           |
|    2 |       2 |           |           |
|    1 |         |           |        16 |
|    1 |         |        16 |           |
|   16 |         |           |           |
|   16 |         |           |         1 |
|   16 |      16 |           |           |
|    1 |         |           |         4 |
|    1 |         |         4 |           |
```

Comment: Yes, this seems nice, but I don't think I need 4 columns. I need only two: `user` and `friend`. If zero rows are returned, then friend request isn't pending, nor the person is a friend. If `user` is found, but `friend` is NULL, then a friend request is pending. If `user` is found and `friend` is found too (> 0), then the person is a friend. Am I right?

Comment: Also, this returns incorrect values. Notice it doesn't say that I'm friends with 2, while in fact I am.

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood you question and thought in rather different manner. I assumed you wanted the query to be dynamic and wanted to see all levels :$ couldn't help...you, but glad someone got you right. I didn't think you wanted  count :(